# tracking web traffic with Python

Tags: python, html

I learned of Compete.com and I am interested in how they track web traffic from other websites. I am most interested in doing this with Python but when I Google I can't find snap. Probably my English. Could someone tell me of existing modules that I may look at, and in general how to track web traffic from other sites (what do they look at when tracking)?

Comment: Good question, but belongs on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics

Read this: http://web.analyticsblog.ca/2010/03/web-page-rank-from-google-alexa-quantcast-and-compete-com/